# PhoneGap- Random Select Database

Tags: sql, cordova

I tried to random select rows in a table with COUNT

```
tx.executeSql("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TABLE" , [], querySuccess, errorCB);
```

But I don't know how to retrieve it. (**results.rows.length** returns 1, I has 5 rows.)
I follow some advice but I'm wondering if there's better solution to do so.

1. COUNT
2. Then var numRand = Math.floor(Math.random()*(TOTALROW+1))
3. Query specific row

***updated***

```
 function queryDB(tx) {
        tx.executeSql("SELECT COUNT(1) FROM WORD" , [], querySuccess, errorCB);
    }

function querySuccess(tx, results) {
   alert(results.rows.item(0));
}
```

For results.rows(0).item(0), It displayed  "Uncaught TypeError: Property 'rows' of object # is not a function".
For results.rows.item(0), It displayed alert "[object OBJECT]".

Answer (score 2):

If you are trying to select a random row from the database, try:

```
SELECT col1, col2
FROM YourTable
ORDER BY RANDOM()
LIMIT 1
```

This will bring back one random row.  This will let you skip your initial call to determine the record count of the table, and pick a random value yourself.

---

It appears that some versions of sqlite have Random disabled, In this case, I think you will probably want to find the count of rows in your table:

```
SELECT COUNT(1)
FROM Table
```

Then you will want to pick a random number in your code, and query for that record.

Currently your `results.rows.length returns 1` because SELECT COUNT(*) ... will only return one row of data, with the columb being the number of rows in the table.

Comment: I am using phoneGap for the database and it said got error near the 1.

Comment: @AmySukumunu I'm sorry - I misread your tags.  It appears that phonegap creates a `sql lite` database, so I changed my answer to reflect the syntax for `sql lite`.

Comment: I get -> sqlite returned: error code = 1, msg = not authorized to use function: random

Comment: I should request by results.rows.item(0)? Thanks for helping. :)

Comment: @AmySukumunu I believe you want your line, or results.rows(0).item(0) to get the count back from the initial query.  If you still have questions, please update your question so we can see the progress you've made, and know where you still need help.

Comment: Hi, I had updated my progress.  I got Uncaught TypeError: Property 'rows' of object #<SQLResultSet> is not a function